# Can a Qt 5 project invoke a Qt 4 project?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

I have built a UI application using Qt 5.7 and an independent widget using Qt 4.8. The widget uses QGIS API, which is incompatible with Qt5. Is there a way to run the widget from the Qt5 based application?

Comment: Just compile QGIS with Qt 5. See [e.g. here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/163272).

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that..I spent a lot of time trying to build QGIS using Qt5 and finally gave up. I wish I could have kept at it, but I am on a tight schedule.

Comment: Did you try a release, or the head of the master branch from git?

Comment: I cloned the master branch from Git. I actually got stuck using CMake..I was unable to find a QWebKit. I read on SO that QWebKit had been replaced by QWebEngine in Qt5 (is that true?). I tried to build QWebKit from its source and failed.

Comment: Don't mess with webkit. There's an option to disable it: do so. It's all very clear when you use cmake via Qt Creator: all the options are neatly presented in a table. I smell an XY problem here: you don't care about Qt 4 or anything like that, you have trivial build issues that you've failed to ask anyone about. You should be able to build it and it shouldn't take you longer than an hour or two to get it done.

Comment: Ok..I will give it a shot. Thanks for all your help. Do you by any chance have any documentation/links that could help me?

Comment: 0. Make sure you can build a test project in Qt Creator. 1. Install and build prerequisites (there are many!). 2. Clone QGIS. 3. Open the `CMakeLists.txt` under Qt Creator. 4. Configuration will fail. Go to the project pane and uncheck the `WITH_QTWEBKIT` option. 5. Retry. Something else will fail, likely it won't find the prerequisites, so you'll have to point it to them.

Comment: What is the exact platform you're building for? State the OS version/distribution version, compiler and exact Qt version, and where you got that Qt from (self-built vs. distribution-provided). If you're on mac, IIRC macports provides qgis with a qt5 variant that just works. I presume many linux distros do the same. You're only likely to run into problems on Windows, where you'll have to build a lot of other software. I recommend using a VM and scripting the whole prerequisite download + build operation so that you can roll back and verify that you've got a reproducible setup. Then use CI!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cant, the Binary Compatibility of Qt5 means that a library build with Qt 4.8 will not run on it. The Api Compatibility was mostly kept, so if you could compile the QGIS on Qt5, then you could run your application on it.

Comment: Would I be able to call it as an external process, perhaps using QProcess? Would that work?